# linq join with single

Tags: linq, lambda

What would be the correct syntax to add a join to this statement?

```
fpItem.MeterUnit  = 
     _database.Meters
        .Single(c=> c.pkMeterID == fpItem.MeterID)
        .luMeterUnit.UnitName;
```

EDIT : I am trying to join Meters with luMeterUnits, and this is how the 2 tables join usually in my other LINQ statements :

```
from m in _database.Meters
join u in _database.luMeterUnits 
on m.MeterReportingUnit equals u.pkMeterUnitID
```

Comment: What are you joining it with, could you please provide more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided LINQ statement is equivalent to this method chains statement:

```
_database.Meters.Join(_database.luMeterUnits,
                      m => m.MeterReportingUnit,
                      u => u.pkMeterUnitID, (m, u) => new { m, u });
```